# Backbone.js | What is the argument passed to any Backbone.js event callback?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

When I tap on a button, I call the changeProfil method:

```
'tap div:first-of-type button:first-of-type': 'changeProfil'
```

I want to know what is the argument passed to this function. I tried:

```
changerProfil: function(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

But I get this error: "json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures"

Also, I can not do console.log. How can I know what is the argument passed?

Comment: *"I can not do `console.log`"* - Uhm, why? Have you tried `console.log(e)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone views use [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) to bind the events and that

> Uses jQuery's `on` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view.

jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) passes a [normalized event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to the event handlers:

> jQuery’s event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

`JSON.stringify` can't serialize arbitrary objects so don't use that, just say `console.log(e)` or even `console.log(arguments)` to see what you're getting passed.